# Combining multiple rows with the same ID, but different 'Yes'/'No' values for several columns, into one row showing all 'Yes'/'No' values

Tags: sql

[image: Table]

For the above table, I need to reduce the rows down to one per Filter ID and have all the possible yes/no values showing for that particular Filter Id

for example:

| Filter ID | Outpatient Prescriptions | Opioid Outpatient Prescriptions | ... | IP Pharmacy Medication Orders - Component Level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Yes | Yes | ... | No |

How is this achieved?

Comment: Please explain the rules for combining the values.

Comment: Im not quite sure what you mean by rules here, but its important to show 'yes' for that Filter ID under the column where they have a 'yes' value in any of the rows. And a 'no' value in the case where the Filter Id has 'no' values for all of the rows (i.e no 'yes' values for any of that particular column)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, for each partition of FilterID value, you want any field that has a yes to be aggregated up as 'Yes', otherwise 'No'. If you group by FilterID then you can handle the rollup using a `CASE SUM CASE`.

```
SELECT
    FilterID,
    Field1Response = CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Field1='Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END,
    Field2Response = CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Field2='Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END ,
    Field3Response = CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Field3='Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END
    ...
FROM
    Data
GROUP BY
    FilterID
```

By the nature of the data, you can also simply use a `MAX`. This is not a good habit of getting into because the values may change over time, however, if the values are always Y or N then you could simply use `MAX`:

```
SELECT
    FilterID,
    Field1Response = MAX(Field1),
    Field2Response = MAX(Field1),
    Field3Response = MAX(Field1)
    ...
FROM
    Data
GROUP BY
    FilterID
```

Comment: Nice trick with the max() there! Many thanks, that has solved it :)